# Database select method gives IndexoutofRangeException

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql

I am tempting to read the database output and the fields are in the database yet it is giving me IndexoutofRangeException error.I declared BLabel like the other values in the database. Any suggestions?

```
SqlConnection dbConn = null;
StringBuilder sqlString = new StringBuilder();
sqlString.Append("SELECT f.*, v.VersionNumber ");
sqlString.Append("FROM PackLabelFormat f, PackLabelVersion v ");
sqlString.Append(" WHERE f.FormatID = @FormatID ");
sqlString.Append(" AND f.FormatID = v.FormatID ");
sqlString.Append(" AND v.VersionID = (SELECT MAX(VersionID) ");
sqlString.Append("FROM PackLabelVersion v2 ");
sqlString.Append("WHERE v2.FormatID = v.FormatID) ");
try
{
   using (dbConn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default["tville"].ToString()))
   {
      SqlCommand cmd = dbConn.CreateCommand();
      cmd.CommandText = sqlString.ToString();
      cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FormatID", FormatID);
      dbConn.Open();

      using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
      {
         if (reader.HasRows)
         {
            reader.Read();
            FormatName = reader["FormatName"].ToString();
            FormatDescription = reader["FormatDescription"].ToString();
            StockID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["StockID"].ToString());
            PrintCode = bool.Parse(reader["PrintPlantCode"].ToString());
            PrintPrice = bool.Parse(reader["PrintPrice"].ToString());
            PrintWeight = bool.Parse(reader["PrintWeight"].ToString());
            CurrentVersion = reader["VersionNumber"].ToString();
            BLabel = bool.Parse(reader["BSupported"].ToString());
            LLabel = bool.Parse(reader["LSupported"].ToString());
         }
         else
         {
            throw new Exception("No LabelFormat found for ID " + this.FormatID.ToString());
         }
      }
   }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   throw ex;
}
finally
{
   if (dbConn != null)
   {
      try { dbConn.Close(); }
      catch { }
   }
}
```

Comment: I can pretty much guarantee it is because one of your field names is incorrect. Debug the reader and print out the field names as seen by your reader. Its normally something silly like "StockID" vs "StockId"

Comment: What is IT.  What line throws the exception?

Comment: @Blam BLabel throws exception

Comment: @chris.ellis unfortunately the naming is correct.

Comment: i suspect statement ->CurrentVersion = reader["VersionNumber"].ToString();  is your CurrentVersion variable is String?

Comment: Are you sure?  Try debug.writeline  reader["BSupported"].ToString()

Comment: This needs a code review urgently. If you say all columns exists, then show your schema.

Comment: @CharmingInferno: means? is it String - no problem with variable?

Comment: FWIW, using the StringBuilder here to build your sql statement hurts you and does not help at all. If you just used regular string concatentation, the compiler would optimize the code to result in a single string literal. Using a StringBuilder forces this work to all occur at runtime, and produces 8 different string values in memory instead of just one.

Comment: Come on anywhere before the line throwing the exception.

Comment: @Yosi little new to this so where can I find that at? Are you meaning my db I'm working out of?

Comment: @Blam I apologize I was not taught how to use it. what using.system extension do you use? I tried diagnostics but it still says unknown type debug.

Comment: May be your column is in the table `PackLabelVersion` and you are actually not selecting it?

Comment: @Yosi it worked fine for the other values just not LLabel and BLabel that I just added.

Comment: Really System.Diagnostics.Debug is unknown?

Comment: @Blam it won't let me use .Debug says it's not necessary. When I use debug.writeline reader["BSupported"].ToString() it says debug is unknown type

Comment: First you report unknown now not necessary?   Come on figure out Debug.WriteLine on your own.  -1

Comment: @Blam you mind taking back your down vote? If you were paying attention you have realized that the two tables were joined. The SELECT clause was only looking for v.VersionNumber not the other two values. Hence why I got the IndexoutofRangeException. So thanks for the judgement please remove your down vote.

Comment: I should have been paying attention?  There is nothing to indicate VersionNumber is a column in f.*.  Did you post the schema as requested in the 7th comment.   Select * is just plain sloppy.  And you reported that was not the line throwing the error.  Yosi it worked fine for the other values just not LLabel and BLabel that I just added.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What was causing the IndexoutofRangeException was that my query was only looking for v.VersionNumber not all the values I was trying to retrieve such as BLabel and LLabel.